# Can I make an MS Access 2016 database output field split over 2 pages?

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I've got a small Microsoft Access 2016 database set up and I have preprinted forms that I need to print the contents of the database on to.

The preprinted paper has a small box on page 1 called Description and then a large box on page 2 called Description Cont. So, I type out my description in my field however on my form for printing the results when I drag the description output field larger (So it goes over the end of page 1 and on to page 2) for some reason my printer ignores the whole of page 1 and simply starts the output field on page 2....

Is there anyway I can force the output field to print over the two pages - or can I limit the output field to say the first 100 characters, then the rest on the second page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a query that splits the description into two parts, and then assign the two fields to the two text boxes on the report.

```
SELECT Left(Description, 100) AS DescPart1,
    Mid(Description, 101) AS DescPart2
FROM mytable
```

Of course it's not very nice if words are split up. So it's better to search for `space` characters.

```vb
Public Function SpaceIndex(sDesc As String) As Long

    Dim S As String

    If Len(sDesc) > 100 Then
        ' Max. 100 characters in the first string
        S = Left(sDesc, 100)
        ' Find last space character in there
        SpaceIndex = InStrRev(S, " ")
    Else
        ' Because we use "SpaceIndex() - 1" in the query
        SpaceIndex = 101
    End If

End Function
```

and

```
SELECT Left(Description, SpaceIndex(Description) - 1) AS DescPart1,
    Mid(Description, SpaceIndex(Description) + 1) AS DescPart2
FROM mytable
```

If you want to go really crazy and fill the first text box as good as possible, you can adapt code from http://www.lebans.com/textwidth-height.htm